# use parseFloat inside of an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can i use parseFloat when data lives inside of an array?

Let's say that i get an api response like this:

```
$scope.response = [{name: "Richard", qty: "350.99"},
{name: "Chuck", qty: "199"},
{name: "Phonenix", qty: "233.77"}]
```

I want to sum the values of `qty`, but i cannot 'cause the data type. If i need to use parseFloat over `qty`, how can i get only those values?

I have to use something like `some()` to get `qty` values?

I'm using AngularJs and Javascript.

Comment: `reduce` it to return a sum. `$scope.response.reduce((a,b) => a + parseFloat(b.qty));`

Comment: Thanx again. Just missing the `,0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the Array and calculate the sum using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const arr = [{
    name: "Richard",
    qty: "350.99"
  },
  {
    name: "Chuck",
    qty: "199"
  },
  {
    name: "Phonenix",
    qty: "233.77"
  }
];

const result = arr.reduce((sum, current) => {
  return sum + parseFloat(current.qty);
}, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You don't need to do the reassignment sum += since reduce passes the return value to each iteration you can just add them together

Answer (score 2):

Use `array#reduce` to sum all `qty` of `response` array.

```js
var response = [{name: "Richard", qty: "350.99"},{name: "Chuck", qty: "199"},{name: "Phonenix", qty: "233.77"}],
    result = response.reduce((sum, {qty}) => sum += +qty, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is cool, I like the destructuring. But isn't the reassignment sum += qty unnecessary when you can just add them together like sum + qty?

Answer (score 2):

You can map the array to return the parseFloat of the qty, then use reduce to add the values.

```js
var response = [{
    name: "Richard",
    qty: "350.99"
  },
  {
    name: "Chuck",
    qty: "199"
  },
  {
    name: "Phonenix",
    qty: "233.77"
  }];

var sum = response.map(function(obj) {
    return parseFloat(obj.qty);
  })
  .reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);
  
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: don't forget the default value to reduce as 2nd param

Comment: Great catch @RaphaMex. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could use reduce for this:

```js
const response = [
  {name: "Richard", qty: "350.99"},
  {name: "Chuck", qty: "199"},
  {name: "Phonenix", qty: "233.77"}
];

const sumQuantities =
  response.reduce((acc, x) =>
    acc + parseFloat(x.qty)
  , 0);
    
console.log(sumQuantities);
```